# Oracle SQL: cannot specify rows separator for sqlldr when loading from a file

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I have a table `DimTime`. Its schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE DimTime ( SK_TimeID NUMBER(11,0) PRIMARY KEY,
                        TimeValue DATE Not NULL,
                        HourID NUMBER(2) Not NULL,
                        HourDesc CHAR(20) Not NULL,
                        MinuteID NUMBER(2) Not NULL,
                        MinuteDesc CHAR(20) Not NULL,
                        SecondID NUMBER(2) Not NULL,
                        SecondDesc CHAR(20) Not NULL,
                        MarketHoursFlag CHAR(5) NOT NULL check (MarketHoursFlag = 'false' or MarketHoursFlag = 'true'),
                        OfficeHoursFlag CHAR(5) NOT NULL check (OfficeHoursFlag = 'false' or OfficeHoursFlag = 'true')
);
```

I am trying to load data from the source file `Time.txt` into it. This file was generated for TPC-DI benchmarking on Oracle Linux 8.6. Here are the first 3 rows:

```
000000|00:00:00|00|00|00|00:00|00|00:00:00|false|false
000001|00:00:01|00|00|00|00:00|01|00:00:01|false|false
000002|00:00:02|00|00|00|00:00|02|00:00:02|false|false
```

I tried to load the data into the table using the following ctl file:

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE DimTime
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    SK_TimeID,
    TimeValue DATE "HH24:MI:SS",
    HourID,
    HourDesc,
    MinuteID,
    MinuteDesc,
    SecondID,
    SecondDesc,
    MarketHoursFlag,
    OfficeHoursFlag
)
```

and running `sqlldr userid=user/password@localhost/db_name control=DimTime.ctl data=path/to/Time.txt`

But the log file states that the last column had an error:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table DIMTIME, column OFFICEHOURSFLAG.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "SAYYUS"."DIMTIME"."OFFICEHOURSFLAG" (actual: 6, maximum: 5)
```

even though it contains only values "true" or "false" (max 5 characters) as can be seen in the sample file.

I am sure, the problem is that as explained by [TPC-DI documentation](https://www.tpc.org/tpc_documents_current_versions/pdf/tpc-di_v1.1.0.pdf), "records have a terminator character appropriate for the System Under Test". So it has a character at the end of each line that is appended to the last column but I cannot discard this character. I tried to put `INFILE "STR X'0A'"` as explained by [this webpage](https://mustafakalayci.me/2019/07/05/insert-multi-line-data-using-sqlldr/) and tried to trim the column in the ctl file: `OfficeHoursFlag "TRIM (:OfficeHoursFlag)"` but it didn't work.

Does anybody know what character is in the end of the line? How is it possible to discard it?

Comment: What about if you try with `"REGEXP_REPLACE(:OfficeHoursFlag, '[^[:print:]]')"` ?

Comment: tested here and it works as is, so question: does the data has been generated on the same OS (same line endings) as the one running sqlldr? If not why just not converting the data to the expected line endings? 
Or:
    OfficeHoursFlag "replace(:OfficeHoursFlag, chr(13), '')"

Comment: Please don't enclose links to data, use the editor's built-in formatting to include the data as text. I'm not going to follow random links on a public website *(I may as well paint "hack me" on my forehead)*.

Comment: The linked Google doc seems to be in Windows format, and it loaded without any problems on Windows. Sounds like you just need to convert it to Linux format prior to loading.

Comment: By the way, although the linked document does describe the table with `char` and `boolean` columns, I imagine you are expected to substitute the equivalent types for your RDBMS. In Oracle we use `varchar2`, and `char` is only provided for portability and standards completeness. This could affect the test results, as your HourDesc column will store values like `'00                  '` (with 18 trailing spaces) which will slow it down unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your attention! @MatBalie I included the sample data in the post like you suggested.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, I checked on Windows and it loaded without any error. For Linux, I could load by replacing the last character of each line with a new line character.

Comment: Does "replacing the last character of each line with a new line character" mean converting from Windows to Linux format? Though Windows files terminate each line with <cr><lf>, so the last character is already a linefeed. Note Linux has a `dos2unix` command that performs the conversion without you having to open the file in a text edit and do a search and replace for carriage returns.

Comment: Yes, I guess I am converting from Windows to Linux this way. Thank you! I will try using `dos2unix`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, `dos2unix` also fixes this error, thank you!